# \autocite removed

Tags: citing

Is the `\autocite` command removed from latex? I used it 2 years ago and now when I try to use it in both texstudio and overleaf, it keeps giving me this error [image: error]
I'm working with a `\begin{document}` file

Comment: Not really related, but every LaTeX document has `\begin{document}`, so that doesn't really narrow things down very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\autocite` was never defined by LaTeX (by that I mean it was never part of the LaTeX kernel/core commands). The command must always have come either from a package (or a specific document class) or other preamble code.

The only package that I know of that defines this command is `biblatex`. In all likelihood, then, you want to load `biblatex` in order to use `\autocite`. (In particular the command is not defined by other popular citation/bibliography packages like `apacite` or `natbib`.)

There has been no recent change with regards to `\autocite` in the `biblatex` package. But the exact output and definition of `\autocite` is up to the (citation) style you are using. (So here and only here is the potential for something to have changed.)

All `biblatex` standard styles will define `\autocite` and will define it in such a way that it produces sensible output. They have done so for years. The vast majority of contributed styles should also at least define `\autocite`, but if you put in some effort it is possible to write `biblatex` styles that do not define `\autocite` or that give it a definition that errors later on.

---

The following example of `\autocite` with `biblatex` has worked the same for several years.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)]